# VS Code Ctrl + S remove formatting - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am working on a React project using Visual Studio Code. when I press Ctrl+S in the Visual Studio Code to save the file. It removes all the Javascript formatting or scatters all the code in the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

my settings.json is

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "javascript.format.enable": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Disable format on save option in VSCode settings under TextEditor Formatting

Comment: is already disable

Comment: check your plugin list you may have install some which format ur react code

Answer (score 6):

Check the extension you installed.

For me, disable "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" extension solved the issue.

Comment: Upvoted.what is interesting here,i didnt install that plugin ever but i found it in list,must be than it comes with some update .